# How to install JIRA-SERVER on OPEN-SHIFT (docker-image)

Tags: docker, openshift, jira

Im trying to installing jira-server via docker-image on openshift.

I pulled the image from docker-desktop for windows. Added simple dockerfile includes USER ROOT etc.

When trying to deploy the pod. I get error and pod enters to loop.
The errror is: Permission Error in diffrent locations.
Tried many times to relocate the jira-home directory but without success.

(Trying to install on closed network)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a more detailed list of the steps you did (e.g. I've got no idea what image tag you used) please?

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

The official Atlassian Images are incompatible with Kubernetes Derivatives /e.g. Openshift as they violate some key concepts.
In Openshift for example, containers are running with arbitrary user ids, which means a nameless user is executing the processes in the container.
This is a safety mechanism, prevents containers running as root and limits the risk of escaping the container gaining privileges on the cluster host.

## Solution

You do need to rebuild the image from scratch.
Furthermore, the behaviour of the startup python script trying to modify file system permissions need to be removed.

1. Clone official Repo
   https://bitbucket.org/atlassian-docker/docker-atlassian-jira/src/master/
2. Modify the Dockerfile and add to the UserGroup creation Step:

```
RUN groupadd --gid ${RUN_GID} ${RUN_GROUP} \
    ...
    && chown -R ${RUN_USER}:${RUN_GROUP}            ${JIRA_HOME} \

    # make the image compatible to run as an arbitrary uid
    && chgrp -R 0 /etc/container_id \ 
    && chmod -R g=u /etc/container_id  \
    && chmod -R 460 /etc/container_id  \
    && chgrp -R 0 ${JIRA_INSTALL_DIR} \ 
    && chmod -R g=u ${JIRA_INSTALL_DIR} \
    && chgrp -R 0 ${JIRA_HOME} \
    && chmod -R g=u ${JIRA_HOME}
```

3. Modify the `gen_cfg` function from `entrypoint_helpers.py` and remove the `else` clause at the end.
   The necessary permissions have already been set in step2.

```py
def gen_cfg(tmpl, target, user='root', group='root', mode=0o644, overwrite=True):
    if not overwrite and os.path.exists(target):
        logging.info(f"{target} exists; skipping.")
        return

    logging.info(f"Generating {target} from template {tmpl}")
    cfg = jenv.get_template(tmpl).render(env)
    try:
        with open(target, 'w') as fd:
            fd.write(cfg)
    except (OSError, PermissionError):
        logging.warning(f"Container not started as root. Bootstrapping skipped for '{target}'")
    # else:
        # set_perms(target, user, group, mode)
```

4. Rebuild the image using the `--build-arg JIRA_VERSION= --build-arg ARTEFACT_NAME`
5. Run and Enjoy

## Detail inspection

Firing up the atlassian images, user root is the first to enter, doing modifications (chown...) and later dropping down to user "jira".
All these operations are not possible in openshift.
In most cases, building a new Dockerfile starting from the official image and modifing permissions of the needed files and folders before deploying to a cluster is the solution,
but to make things worse, atlassian choose to "mount" the necessary directories as VOLUME.

They have even referenced the issue in their comments.

```
VOLUME ["${JIRA_HOME}"] # Must be declared after setting perms
```

After the volume mount, the permissions can only be modified persistently at runtime.
This forces them to rebuild and set permissions after container startup, using a python function in the `entrypoint_helpers.py`.
This is also the place, where the container fails with several "permission denied"s.

Would be glad to issue a pull request on this, but unfortunatelly they are hosted on bitbucket.